# Property 'registerComponent' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'

Tags: angular, golden-layout

I was trying to work on golden-layout with angular2. I followed this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FITTtt?p=preview), but I got following errors:

> Property 'registerComponent' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property 'eventHub' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property'init' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property 'on' does notexist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property 'updateSize' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property 'eventHub' does not exist on type
>    'ElementRef'

The code of plunked is as:

```
import {
  Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, HostListener, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef,ViewContainerRef,ReflectiveInjector,
  ElementRef, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {App2Component} from './app2.component';
declare let GoldenLayout: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'golden-layout',
  template: `<div style="width:100%;height:500px;" id="layout" #layout>My First Angular 2 App</div>
  <br/><button (click)="sendEvent()">Send event through hub</button>`,
  entryComponents: [AppComponent, App2Component]
})
export class GLComponent {
  @ViewChild('layout') private layout: ElementRef;
  private config: any;
  private layout: ElementRef;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){
    this.config = {
            content: [{
                type: 'row',
                content: [{
                    type: 'component',
                    componentName: 'test1',
                    componentState: {
                      message:"Top Left"
                    }
                }, { 
                        type: 'column',
                        content: [{
                            type: 'component',
                            componentName: 'test2',
                            componentState: {
                              message:"Top Right"
                            }
                        }, {
                                type: 'component',
                                componentName: 'test1',
                                componentState: {
                                  message:"Bottom Right"
                                }
                            }]
                    }]
            }]
        };
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.layout = new GoldenLayout(this.config, this.layout.nativeElement);

    this.layout.registerComponent('test1', (container, componentState) => {
          let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppComponent);

          let compRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
          compRef.instance.setEventHub(this.layout.eventHub);
          compRef.instance.message = componentState.message;
          container.getElement().append(compRef.location.nativeElement); 

          container["compRef"] = compRef;

          compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }); 

    this.layout.registerComponent('test2', (container, componentState) => {
          let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(App2Component);

          let compRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
          compRef.instance.setEventHub(this.layout.eventHub);
          compRef.instance.message = componentState.message;
          container.getElement().append(compRef.location.nativeElement); 

          container["compRef"] = compRef;

          compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }); 

    this.layout.init();

        this.layout.on("itemDestroyed", item => {
            if (item.container != null) {
                let compRef = item.container["compRef"];
                if (compRef != null) {
                    compRef.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
      if (this.layout)
        this.layout.updateSize();
  }

  sendEvent(){
    if (this.layout)
      this.layout.eventHub.emit("someEvent");
  }
}
```

**Edit:** 
I am adding github link to my project, with all config files and components: [golden-layout-demo](https://github.com/prashantprabhakar/golden-layout-demo/tree/development/my-app).

**Solution:** 
The code of the plunker was incorrect, used `this.layout.nativeElement.registerComponent` instead of `this.layout.registerComponent` and same for Same if for `eventHub, init, on, updateSize`. This resolved the compile time errors.

**Edit2**:

Now, I am getting the runtime error, that I can see in my browser:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/styles.css 
GET http://localhost:4200/systemjs.config.js 
GET http://localhost:4200/systemjs.config.js 
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
GET http://localhost:4200/app 404 (Not Found)
GLComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerComponent' of undefined
```

The contents of my index file look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://golden-layout.com/files/latest/css/goldenlayout-base.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://golden-layout.com/files/latest/css/goldenlayout-dark-theme.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://golden-layout.com/files/latest/js/goldenlayout.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.8"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      // System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
       System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <golden-layout>Loading...</golden-layout>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same code as the Plunker?

Comment: Yes. I have posted the code too.

Comment: So the question is about what the same code works in Plunker but not on your local machine?

Comment: yes, I am completly new to angular, unable to figure out the problem, the code in plunked works like fab but fails on my local machine.

Comment: Hard to tell. If the code you posted above is the same as in the Plunker, then there probably isn't anything wrong with this code.

Comment: I can post the link of the demo project with config files, if that can help to find the issue?

Comment: Sure, but I won't be able to help you with that. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated the solution to my question but now I am facing a new issue, can you please check if index.html has anything to do with it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about `GoldenLayout`

Comment: First change your `index.html` like http://take.ms/ToMHW

Comment: Then copy `gl.component.ts` from this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8uFyM?p=preview to your project

Comment: @yurzui Thanks.. you solved all the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the plunk is not incorrect, changing `this.layout.registerComponent` to `this.layout.nativeElement.registerComponent` is just hiding the problem and will cause more problems once the application can actually build.

Your application is running using webpack via Angular CLI whereas the application in the plunk is using SystemJS

You have ended up merging the two when trying to implement the plunk in your application and this is causing your issues. You do not need the Load libraries and configure SystemJS sections in the `index.html` as @yurzui mentioned and you also don't need the `systemjs.config.js` file

Comment: Great. Let me check that. Thanks for taking time to the answer and letting me know I was doing it complete wrong. Will apply your suggestions and see if it works. +1 for the answer.